# Retrieve the content of multiples row and columns with Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

i want to retrieve specified columns and rows from an NumericMAtrix.
dis is an NumericMatrix and i want to acces some columns and row based on sppInSample
This is my code snippet (this is not the complete code):

```
NumericVector mpdCppV2(NumericMatrix samp, NumericMatrix dis, bool abundance_weighted = false) {
  int N = samp.nrow();
  NumericVector mpd(N);
  Rcout << "The value of v : \n";

  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    NumericVector row_i = samp(i, _);
      CharacterVector sppInSample = as<CharacterVector>(colnames(samp))[row_i > 0];

 if (sppInSample.length() > 1) {

   Rcout << "The value of sppInSample : " << sppInSample << "\n";
   NumericMatrix sample_dis = dis(sppInSample, sppInSample);


}
}
return mpd;

}
```

The NumericMatrix samp look like this :

```
        t4 t5 t9 t8 t1 t2 t3 t10 t7 t6
clump1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0  0  1
clump2a  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1  1  0
clump2b  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   1  1  1
clump4   1  0  1  0  1  0  0   0  0  0
even     0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1  1  1
random   0  1  1  1  0  0  1   0  0  1
```

and the NumericMatrix dis look like this :

```
  t5        t7       t1        t4       t6        t3       t10       t8
t5  0.0000000 0.8804987 1.323180 1.0106683 2.968295 3.6189006 3.5768501 2.047356
t7  0.8804987 0.0000000 1.285754 0.9732425 3.385655 4.0362613 3.9942108 2.464716
t1  1.3231796 1.2857538 0.000000 1.3278116 3.828336 4.4789422 4.4368917 2.907397
t4  1.0106683 0.9732425 1.327812 0.0000000 3.515825 4.1664308 4.1243803 2.594886
t6  2.9682947 3.3856554 3.828336 3.5158249 0.000000 1.1094981 1.0674476 1.093657
t3  3.6189006 4.0362613 4.478942 4.1664308 1.109498 0.0000000 0.7136734 1.744263
t10 3.5768501 3.9942108 4.436892 4.1243803 1.067448 0.7136734 0.0000000 1.702212
t8  2.0473557 2.4647164 2.907397 2.5948859 1.093657 1.7442627 1.7022122 0.000000
t2  2.8165982 3.2339589 3.676640 3.3641284 2.372962 3.0235676 2.9815171 1.452023
t9  3.2205643 3.6379250 4.080606 3.7680945 2.776928 3.4275338 3.3854833 1.855989
          t2       t9
t5  2.816598 3.220564
t7  3.233959 3.637925
t1  3.676640 4.080606
t4  3.364128 3.768095
t6  2.372962 2.776928
t3  3.023568 3.427534
t10 2.981517 3.385483
t8  1.452023 1.855989
t2  0.000000 1.171212
t9  1.171212 0.000000
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: This is likely going to be easier with `RcppArmadillo`.  Search for existing answer here and also glance at the (well done, readable, extensive) docs at the [armadillo site](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html).

Comment: I updated my code example of the variable dis and sample